# delete in multiple datagrids

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have three datagrids: MasterDatagrid, DetailDatagrid, AssocationDatagrid.
Bascially, if i select one row in one of the grid, i press 'delete' key to remove a row from that grid.

```
   private void MasterDataGrid_IsMouseCapturedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
??
        }
```

how can i replicate this function in my delete button ? how can i detect where my mouse focus is? and how to detect  the right datagrid i am in?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

You can define a focus scope in the xaml on your page or user control using  [FocusManager.IsFocusScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.isfocusscope.aspx).

Then on the `OnClicked` event of your button you can get the focused element using [FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604088%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.

From there you can get the required item using SelectedItem(s) property and delete it.

Comment: thanks, but seems like it has some conflicts with command binding 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/54bf3d7e-ffc6-4717-a821-25cca8c0b1cc